# Android Webview Videos or Youtube throws errors

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, crash

I am using Android webview, its a simple browser app (my first app BTW:)). When I browse, everything looks fine. All the websites load correctly....

When I go to CNN.com or youtube.com, it loads correctly... Now comes the issue!

When I click on any video (any website), the video starts to play BUT, I see uncontrollable errors as below in logcat, until the app crashes or phone soft reboots. I say uncontrollable because, it shows every second and once it reaches about 1500 errors, app crashes....

```
mOnSeekCompleteListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SEEK_COMPLETE message.
mOnVideoSizeChangedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE message.

mOnBufferingUpdateListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE message.
```

the last error throws about 1500 times till the app crash.

Any advice or help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you shold try to set WebChromeClient to your WebView? Simple code line: webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient);